# Symfony 4 - Problem with pagination filter search

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

in my project Symfony 4 I created a pagination service.
In my controller, I declare it like this:

```
$pagination->setEntityClass(User::class)
                ->setLimit(5)
                ->setPage($page);
```

And in this case it displays the list of all my users with a pagination.

But in my page, I inserted a search box to search for users by their first name or last name.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVgsj.png)

And when the user performs a search and submits the form by clicking "Search", in my controller, I have a check that is done every time.

```
$name = $request->get('champRecherche');
```

If the $ name is null, then I perform a global search as shown in the code above.
But if $ name is different from null, then I submitted the search form with something in the search field, and in this case the code will be:

```
$parametres = ['name' => $name];
            $pagination->setEntityClass(User::class)
                ->setLimit(2)
                ->setPage($page)
                ->setFunctionToCall('getUsersByName')
                ->setParameters($parametres);
```

I tell my service what function the repository should use, and I insert the parameters.

So everything works fine. If I put something in my search field and validate, it puts me well what I ask, with the pagination below.

But suddenly, if there are several pages, and I ask to go to page 2, in the controller he will believe that I ask for a global search since the search form was not submitted, and therefore instead to show me page number 2 on the list of users I have filtered, it will show me page 2 on all users. And that's where I do not know how to handle this problem

My Twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}


    <form action="{{ path('rh_index') }}" method="POST">

        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('rh_index') }}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Entrer le nom de l'utilisateur" type="text" name="champRecherche" id="champRecherche"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search" value="Chercher">Chercher</button>
                <a href="{{ path('rh_index') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Afficher tous</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form><br>
    <table class="table table-hover align-items-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for user in pagination.data %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{user.fullName}}</th>
                    <th>{{user.groupe.nom}}</th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Voir</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>


    {{pagination.display}}



{% endblock %}
```

My Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/rh/{page<\d+>?1}", name="rh_index")
     */
    public function index($page, Request $request, PaginationService $pagination)
    {


        $name = $request->get('champRecherche');


        if ($name != null) {
            $token = $request->get('token');
            if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('rh_index', $token)) {
                throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException('Accès interdit');
            }

            //$pagination = $repoUser->getUsersByName($name);
            $parametres = ['name' => $name];
            $pagination->setEntityClass(User::class)
                ->setLimit(1)
                ->setPage($page)
                ->setFunctionToCall('getUsersByName')
                ->setParameters($parametres);
        } else {
            $pagination->setEntityClass(User::class)
                ->setLimit(5)
                ->setPage($page);

            // $users = $repoUser->getUsers();
        }

        return $this->render('rh/index.html.twig', [
            'pagination' => $pagination
        ]);
    }
```

My service display function :

```
 /**
     * Permet d'afficher le rendu de la navigation au sein d'un template twig !
     * 
     * On se sert ici de notre moteur de rendu afin de compiler le template qui se trouve au chemin
     * de notre propriété $templatePath, en lui passant les variables :
     * - page  => La page actuelle sur laquelle on se trouve
     * - pages => le nombre total de pages qui existent
     * - route => le nom de la route à utiliser pour les liens de navigation
     *
     * Attention : cette fonction ne retourne rien, elle affiche directement le rendu
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function display()
    {
        //  $parametres = $this->convertParametersForTwig();
        // dd($parametres);

        $this->twig->display($this->templatePath, [
            'page' => $this->currentPage,
            'pages' => $this->getPages(),
            'route' => $this->route,
        ]);
    }
```

And my pagination template :

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item {% if page == 1 %}disabled{% endif %}">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{path(route,{'page': page - 1})}}">&laquo;</a>
        </li>
        {% for i in 1..pages %}
            <li class="page-item {% if page == i %}active {% endif %}">
                <a class="page-link" href="{{path(route,{'page':i})}}">{{i}}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

        <li class="page-item {% if page == pages %}disabled{% endif %}">
            <a class="page-link" href="{{path(route,{'page': page + 1})}}">&raquo;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you should probably show your controller and template code! usually, the link to another page must include: the page number and all previously submitted parameters. unless you show your controller its hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I updated my first post

Comment: okay, *usually* Pagination objects have some function to generate the pagination links, which will usually also include the search/filter data, which your current `path` calls are missing, ... hence they are disappearing on page change. Since I'm not quite certain, which kind of PaginationService you're using, I can't give specific code, but you will surely find something in the appropriate documentation! ;o)